# Найти и вывести даты в тексте

Tags: c, дата, время

Необходимо реализовать функцию, которая будет искать в тексте даты вида "dmy" и выводить их по возрастанию, в формате "DD:MM:YYYY". Пример даты в тексте: "d14m04y0987"
Каким образом можно найти дату в тексте?

Comment: Вы забыли написать, на каком конкретно месте у вас возникла проблема :)

Comment: Очень простым способом - идти по тексту и искать нужный паттерн.